# Writing into binary file with the std::ostream_iterator

Tags: c++, stream, iterator

Consider the following piece of code:

```
std::vector<long> d(3);
d[0] = 0;
d[1] = 1;
d[2] = 2;

std::ofstream f("d:/ofstream.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
std::ostream_iterator<long> out(f);

std::copy(std::begin(d), std::end(d), out);
```

The resulting file size is 3 bytes, so it is written as `char`, not `long`. Can I use `std::ostream_iterator` at all in this case?

I cannot understand its behaviour here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `std::stream_iterator` uses the "normal" **`operator<<` semantics, it is a formatted output (not binary)**.

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator);

> `std::ostream_iterator` is a single-pass OutputIterator that writes successive objects of type `T` into the `std::basic_ostream` object for which it was constructed, using `operator<<`. Optional delimiter string is written to the output stream after every write operation. The write operation is performed when the iterator (whether dereferenced or not) is assigned to. Incrementing the `std::ostream_iterator` is a no-op.

You could implement a custom iterator that writes the unformatted output to a stream; it will be required to follow the same constraints as the `std::stream_iterator` w.r.t. the iterator requirements, in particular

> `operator=` writes a object to the associated output sequence

In this case, the object should be written to the stream as unformatted data (the raw binary contents). Your exact implementation may vary, but here we use a simple binary dump for demonstration purposes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

template <class T, class CharT = char, class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>>
class ostreambin_iterator :
    public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void> {
public:
    typedef std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits> ostream_type;
    typedef Traits traits_type;
    typedef CharT  char_type;

    ostreambin_iterator(ostream_type& stream) : stream_(stream) { }

    ostreambin_iterator& operator=(T const& value) 
    {
        // basic implementation for demonstration
        stream_.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&value), sizeof(T));
        return *this;
    }

    ostreambin_iterator& operator*()     { return *this; }
    ostreambin_iterator& operator++()    { return *this; }
    ostreambin_iterator& operator++(int) { return *this; }

protected:
    ostream_type& stream_;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<long> d(3);
    d[0] = 0x303030; // test some width past a single byte
    d[1] = 0x31;
    d[2] = 0x32;

    ostreambin_iterator<long> out(cout);

    cout << "begin" << endl;
    copy(std::begin(d), std::end(d), out);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "end" << endl;
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/737f78eea6b6d9c8).

I've used `cout` for the demo (so the `NULL` bytes may not be visible on your console).

Comment: Does it need increment  for this pointer for post and pre increment implementation?

Comment: @Steephen. No, for the `ostream_iterator` that this `ostreambin_iterator` models, the pre and post increment operators are no-op. This makes sense, since the stream itself manages the position, insertion etc. in the underlying buffer.